# SQL How do to a where statement and switch the columns your joining

Tags: sql, join

basically I have 2 tables, `tableA and tableB`.   For simple example sake, both tables have the same int columns.  `MyInt1 and MyInt2`.  Well what I want to do is this.

When MyInt2 `is null`, i just want to join tableA to tableB on `tableA.MyInt1 = tableB.MyInt1`

when MyInt2 `is not null`, I want to join it like this `tableA.MyInt1 = tableB.MyInt1 and tableA.MyInt2 = tableB.MyInt2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a complicated `case` statement:

```
on 1 = (case when tableA.MyInt1 is not null or tableB.MyInt1 is not null and
                  tableA.MyInt1 = tableB.MyInt1
             then 1
             when tableA.MyInt2 = tableB.MyInt2
             then 1
        end)
```

EDIT:

In practice, I'd be inclined to split this into two joins and use `coalesce()` to prioritize in the `select`:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.col, b2.col)
from tableA a left join
     tableB b1
     on a.MyInt1 = b1.MyInt1 left join
     tableB b2
     on a.MyInt2 = b2.MyInt2;
```

This will not always work -- for instance, there are unexpected results if there is more than one match in `tableB`.  But, this structure works better because it is easier to optimize.